# What is this rubber thing on the floor near my toilet?

Tags: bathroom

A couple night ago, I found this rubber thing on the bathroom floor near my toilet. Anyone know what it is?

[image: Rubber thing]

Comment: It looks like a rubber stopper for a sink or bathtub (for those that don't have the pop-up type).

Comment: @ChrisM. Sounds like an answer to me.